# How to treat null values after joining multiple tables

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation

I am creating a new dataframe by joining 4 dataframes
After which I need to concatenate two same columns from different dataframes
data:

```
col1   col2 expected
Acc1   Acc1 Acc1Acc1
Acc2   null Acc2
null   Acc3 Acc3
```

Issue:
If i do concat without replacing null values; i loose info
So after joining; since pyspark doesnt delete the common columns, we have two Account columns from 2 tables
I tried replacing it with empty string;it didnt work and throws error : dataframe is not iteratable

Query:
How do I replace null values with empty string after joining tables?
or is there any way null and concat can be handled at the sametime?

```
df = df1\
.join(df2,"code",how = 'left') \
.join(df3,"id",how = 'left')\
.join(df4,"id",how = 'left')\
.withColumn('Account',F.when(df2('Account').isNull(),'').otherwise(df2('Account')))\
.withColumn('Account',F.when(df3('Account').isNull(),'').otherwise(df3('Account')))\
.withColumn("Account",F.concat(F.trim(df2.Account), F.trim(df3.Account)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. A function such as `pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws` should do the trick here, such as:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "John", "Smith"),
    (2, "Monty", "Python"), 
    (3, "Donald", None), 
], ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname'] 
)
df.show()
+---+---------+--------+
| id|firstname|lastname|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|     John|   Smith|
|  2|    Monty|  Python|
|  3|   Donald|    null|
+---+---------+--------+

df.select(
    "*",
    f.concat_ws(
      "", 
      f.trim(f.col("firstname")), f.trim(f.col("lastname"))
    ).alias("concatenated")
).show()
+---+---------+--------+------------+
| id|firstname|lastname|concatenated|
+---+---------+--------+------------+
|  1|     John|   Smith|   JohnSmith|
|  2|    Monty|  Python| MontyPython|
|  3|   Donald|    null|      Donald|
+---+---------+--------+------------+
```

Hope this helps, you can find more about the function in here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat

Comment: Hello,Thank you for this, However, the issue arises after joining....since both the columns have same name...i use withColumn and used tablename['colname]...which didnt work..how do I use the concat function after joining